# Gmail - Google Apps - Inbox Folders Clipped by Google Window

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, formatting

I usually don't bother with it, but lately it has bothered me more.  Is there a way to make it so that I can actually view the obscured folders in the below picture?  **Inbox/Co-Workers** > I can't quite read these...

[alt text http://nicorellius.com/images/gmail_inbox_folder.jpg](http://nicorellius.com/images/gmail_inbox_folder.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have GMail Labs enabled you can use the "Nested Labels" feature:

> Nested Labels by Manu C
>
> Manage your email by sorting it into a
>   hierarchy of labels. Add slashes (/)
>   to label names to express inheritance.
>   For example, if you want a Home label
>   with two child labels named Kids and
>   Shopping, create the three following
>   labels: Home, Home/Kids and
>   Home/Shopping.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox/Mozilla Solution:
[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) Plugin - Allows you to change the CSS of any webpage.

Knowledge of CSS required.